# How to show the view from bottom while recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having 15 to 30 items in my recyclerview. At the End of the recyclerview I want to show the Image/Layout at bottom. This image will slowly come to top while scroll the recylerview to top. When the list end the image/layout will fully shown. If we scroll down the recyclerview the image/layout should go down. If I stop the scroll at middle the image/layout will show partially. For example the Image/Layout height will be 100 dp. it will be placed in the bottom. It will not visible at first time. When we scroll the Recyclerview that view will be slowly appear. Please give me any idea to achieve this. Sorry for my bad English.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Will show while Scroll"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Scrolling Recyclerview

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    
               if (dy > 0) {
                    footerHeight = +10;
                    bottomView.setTranslationY(footerHeight);
                    Log.i("Test","...Scrolling up");
                } else {
                    footerHeight = -10;
                    bottomView.setTranslationY(footerHeight);
                    Log.i("Test","...Scrolling down");
                }
             }
    
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    
                    switch (newState) {
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                            Log.i("Test","...The RecyclerView is not scrolling");
                            break;
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                            Log.i("Test","...Scrolling now");
                            break;
                        case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                            Log.i("Test","...Scroll Settling");
                            break;
    
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here I just increase/decrease the bottomX view while scrolling. But still I am missing something.

OP:
[image]

In this image bottom view is showing always. But initially it want view should be hidden state. While scroll up Bottom view slowly come up. If I scroll down Bottom view should slowly goes down.

Comment: i think video or gif will be very helpful to understand your case

Comment: I just alter the code. Please verify. i will try to add Gif also.

Comment: In simple word sticky footer.

Comment: @Wini I added Gif for the reference. Please verify.

Comment: I just had few doubts... So when user scroll up the view slowly comes up till the end of the lists and when scroll down view slowly fades/hidden away?

Comment: @Wini Yes.. you are are right..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new project and try this:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int DATA_LIST_SIZE = 50;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView footer;
ArrayList<SampleData> dataArrayList;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

int totalHeight = -1;
int invisibleHeight = -1;
int scrolledHeight = -1;
int childHeight = -1;
int footerHeight = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    footer = findViewById(R.id.text_view_footer);

    dataArrayList = genSampleDataList();
    CustomRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(dataArrayList);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    footer.measure( View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    footerHeight = footer.getMeasuredHeight();

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            View firstVisibleView = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
            if (invisibleHeight == -1) {
                childHeight = linearLayoutManager.getDecoratedMeasuredHeight(firstVisibleView);
                totalHeight = childHeight * DATA_LIST_SIZE;
                invisibleHeight = totalHeight - recyclerView.getHeight() + footerHeight;
            }
            scrolledHeight = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() * childHeight +
                    recyclerView.getTop() - firstVisibleView.getTop();
            int newRecyclerViewHeight = totalHeight - invisibleHeight + footerHeight -
                    scrolledHeight * footerHeight / invisibleHeight;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newRecyclerViewHeight);
            recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);

            footer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255 * (invisibleHeight - scrolledHeight) / invisibleHeight,
                    255 * scrolledHeight / invisibleHeight, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<SampleData> genSampleDataList() {
    ArrayList<SampleData> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < DATA_LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        tmpList.add(new SampleData("Item " + (i + 1), "Description " + (i + 1)));
    }
    return tmpList;
}
}
```

SampleData.java:

```
public class SampleData {
String name;
String description;

public SampleData(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<SampleData> dataList;

public CustomRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<SampleData> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    SampleData sampleData = dataList.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(sampleData.name);
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(sampleData.description);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewDescription;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Will show while Scroll"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

item_view.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OMG. What a effort. Thank you very much. This what exactly I want. No words to say..!! Thanks Again..!!

Answer (score 1):

One solution if I've read your question correctly is in your model class to include link or Uri of ImageView in a String.

Then in your RecyclerView adapter do some boolean checking to see if item added has a link to it and if it has load it with library called Picasso for example. Picasso is simple just one line of code. If you are using image from phone you might just add uri to image.

And when items are added on last item add link to image or set it yourself.

Comment: No. This is not my requirement. I think I confused you. Now I added the code snippet for better understand.

Comment: Layout/Or image will be created at the beginning. I just want to show slowly while scroll up. Want to hide slowly while scroll down. If we stop scroll at the middle layout will show partially.